# A question on parallelizable manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a manifold with the property that $f^{*}(TM)$ is isomorphic to TM, for every diffeomorphism $f$ on $M$. Does this imply that $M$ is parallelizable?

Comment: Doesn't every diffeomorphism $f : M \to N$ induce an isomorphism $df : TM \to f^\ast TN$?

Comment: $df$ cover $f$, but an isomorphism of two vector bundles on $M$ must cover $Id_{M}$

Comment: Since $df : TM \to TN$ covers $f$, it induces a map $TM \to f^\ast TN$ over $\mathrm{id}_M$, which I also called $df$ above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the 2-dimensional sphere a counterexample? If $f$ has degree 1, then it's homotopic to the identity, so $f^*(TM)\cong TM$.  If $f$ has degree $-1$, then it's homotopic to the antipode map $a$, so $f^*(TM)\cong a^*(TM)\cong TM$, where the last $\cong$ is evident if we embed the sphere in the standard way in $\mathbb R^3$ so that the tangent spaces at a point and its antipode are the same as vector spaces.  Since a diffeomorphism must have degree $\pm1$, we have $f^*(TM)\cong TM$ in all cases.  But even-dimensional spheres don't admit even one nowhere-vanishing vector field, because they have non-zero Euler characteristic, so they are far from parallelizable.

Comment: why $S^{2}$ is  a counterexample?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I edited a proof into my answer.